# Microsoft OneDrive on MacOs - How to choose folders to sync before the sync starts?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, onedrive, microsoft-onedrive

I have been using OneDrive quite a long time. In general I was very happy. But as the amount of the data grew at the cloud I started to face issues that I can not find a workaround for.

The data at OneDrive that I keep is around 200GB and I am not keeping most of the data in my local machine, to save disk space. (I excluded some of the heavy folders from synchronization.)

For some reason I signed out of the OneDrive. Now I am trying to sign in so that the synchronization process may continue as before.

But I am not able to exclude the heavy folders from being sync'ed. As soon as I sign in, OneDrive rushes to sync (download) all folders to my local machine, and since I don't have enough disk space it will crash if i don't stop. But if I pause or stop the sync I can not change the folders that are to be synced.

OneDrive allows choosing folders only when the sync is running. But in this case, it gives following error, if I try to modify the folders that are to be sync'ed:

[image]

So my question is, how to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following workaround.

1. Remove OneDrive completely.
2. Download and re-install OneDrive.
3. When first time opening the OneDrive, do **NOT** login from the regular top menu icon, but it asks folder setup, login from that screen.
4. When you login from this path, it asks you your local folder and remote folders to be synchronized. Use this method to choose the folders to be excluded.